# pandas mean function returning NaN

Tags: python, pandas, slice, nan, mean

I know this may be a newbie question, so please forgive me, but I have not found an answer which seems to make sense to/help me. I am importing data from a .csv file and need to slice out a particular part. I have done that and when I print the data frame and all values I need are present.

```
    df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/df.csv')
    dfr = df[44:58] #rows I need
    dfrc = dfr[['1','2','3','4','5']] #columns I need
    dfrc.mean(axis=1 skipna=True) #there are some NaNs present in the last index
```

What is returned

```
    44   NaN
    ...
    57   NaN
    dtype: float64
```

I am not sure why that is, but I need the numerical value for the mean of the index/row. I was hoping someone on the forum would be able to help. Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal dataframe that reproduces this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure your data is really numeric (int or float)? Maybe you should try cast your columns before, and see if an error is raised.

```
dfrc = dfrc.astype(float)
```